# REGEX para remover sites, e-mails

Tags: python, regex

Quero remover os endereços de sites, e-mails, etc...

```
url_regex = re.compile(r'(?i)(<|\[)?(https?|www)?(.*)?\.(.*){2,4}')
mail_regex = re.compile(r'(?i)(<|\[)?@(.*)\.(.*){2,3}')
```

Desta forma, eu poderia remover por exemplo:

> http://www.google.com.br
>
> http://www.twitter.com
>
> [image.jpeg]
>
> www.facebook.com
>
> [www.amazon.com]
>
> MARIN@blabla.jp
>
> vairegex@python.br
>
> ...

Quando testadas em um texto, essas regex fazem match com o texto todo e nao apenas com os endereços site/emails.

Comment: E a dúvida/problema é qual exatamente?

Comment: Ah desculpa. É que aundo eu testo em um texto, essas regex pegam o texto todo. Muito estranho... eu achei que estava bem preciso nas regex onde era para parar depois do "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problemas dessas expressões regulares estão no operador `.*`. O operador `*` é guloso, ou seja, ele vai tentar casar com o máximo possível de caracteres da string.

O ideal é sempre que possível, construir uma expressão regular que tenha um critério de parada. Por exemplo, uma URL ou um endereço de e-mail podem ter espaço em branco? Se não puderem, o seu critério de parada é o carácter em branco. Ou então um e-mail ou URL só podem ter letras, números e alguns caracteres (., -, _). Então você pode casar com todos até encontrar um carácter que não seja um desses.

Vamos definir que um e-mail tem apenas letras, números e alguns caracteres (., -, _) e tem um `@` no meio. Uma expressão regular para validar e-mail é [beemm mais complexa que isso](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), mas essa aceita 98% dos e-mails existentes.

```
mail_regex = re.compile('([a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Nessa expressão regular, temos 2 partes, uma que aceita 1 ou mais caracteres de a a z, números e os 3 caracteres especiais que definimos. Esperamos depois disso um carácter @ e depois a segunda parte, onde aceitamos as mesmas coisas da primeira parte.

Para casar com uma url é a mesma coisa, a diferença é que nossa ancora está no começo do texto (`http://`, `www` ou `[`).

```
url_regex  = re.compile('((http://|www|\[)[a-z0-9_.-]+]?)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Nessa expressão regular, olhamos primeiro para o começo do texto para ver se tem `http://`, `www` ou `[`. Caso tenha, olhamos se tem letras, números e afins. A única diferença aqui é que também olhamos o ultimo caractere, se não é `]`, no caso da URL ser cercada por colchetes.

Finalmente, rodando essas expressões no texto que você postou, temos o seguinte resultado:

```
print (mail_regex.sub('E-MAIL', text))
http://www.google.com.br

http://www.twitter.com

[image.jpeg]

www.facebook.com

[www.amazon.com]

E-MAIL

E-MAIL
```

E nas urls:

```
print (url_regex.sub('URL', text))
URL

URL

URL

URL

URL

MARIN@blabla.jp

vairegex@python.br
```